# How to fix StackOverflowError when building NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> in scaffold: flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stack-overflow

this is my first project using flutter with firebase but I am getting this error due to the ExerciseStream class below.
I think its something with the list view.
The error is referring to the scaffold widget, although by deleting things I've concluded that the error is from the ExerciseStream class but,
I still don't know how to resolve the issue.

// Error

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

The following StackOverflowError was thrown building NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>:
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  Scaffold
```

// HomePage class

```
    Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            // remove the back button
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0.0,
            title: const Text('WorkoutBeast'),
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
             ),
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: const [
//error
              ExerciseStream(),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

// ExerciseStream class

```
class ExerciseStream extends HomePage {
  const ExerciseStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: users
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid.toString())
            .collection('workout')
            .orderBy('exerciseName', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.requireData.size,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return CreateCard(
                            context,
                            snapshot,
                            index,
                            users,
                            repsController,
                            setsController,
                            weightController,
                            restController,
                            _focusNode,
                            control,
                            onchanged,
                            _hint);
                      }),
                );
              } else {
                return const Center(child: Text('No Data'));
              }
            }
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've trimmed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a lot of investigation I've found the solution:
I've extended the homePage in the ExerciseStream class,
solution:
instead of extending the homepage, extend `StatelessWidget`
like so:

```
class ExerciseStream extends HomePage
```

to

```
class ExerciseStream extends StatelessWidget
```